# Component Identification / 1995 F150 5.8L 351W

Tags: ford, part-identification, f-150, egr

Can someone tell me what components these are?  The rubber hoses on them are cracking and I'd like to try and get OEM since there are 90° bends in the hoses.  Also, I'm genuinely curious as to what system it's attached to. Does it have to do with the EGR?

It's on a 1995 F150 with the 5.8L 351W

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you have circled in the first image is the Vapor Canister Purge Valve / Solenoid:

[image]

I found it [here on RockAuto.com](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/ford,1995,f-150,5.8l+v8,1122297,exhaust+&+emission,vapor+canister+purge+valve+/+solenoid,4936) (NOTE: I have no affiliation with RockAuto, just showing the information).

This is an emissions part, but is separate from the EGR. It should be plumbed from the fuel tank (or charcoal canister) to the intake manifold.

Comment: That helps immensely.  Now I know what hoses to search for!

Comment: @Allan - While I get going OEM on it, you should be able to use some fuel line of the same inside diameter to do the job. The length of the tube is way more than long enough to do the 90° transition. I'd bet the cost of regular ole fuel line would be a lot cheaper than buying OEM from Ford.

Comment: True, but there's also that short piece in the second pic.

Comment: I was able to get an after market "hard plastic elbow" specifically for vacuum lines as well as some quality vacuum hose and ended up making (IMO) a better than OEM 90° fitting.  The problem was that it was two different sizes on each end. What the Ford engineers were thinking when they came up with that design, I'll never know.

Comment: @Allan ... doesn't surprise me one little bit. Glad you were able to get get it fixed.